# XCode image asset folder icon

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, assets

Why some of my image asset folder is dimmed but some are not?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the source pic there?i guess you are lack of these source file.If you can offer  more info,good to judge the root cause..